# Firebase profile picture dissappears on page reload

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, vuex

looking for a bit of help

I am using vue together with vuex and firebase for an app I'm building. I have been able to enable the user upload a profile picture from thier computer to firebase storage and the image is also displayed on their dashboard. The issue is this, when I refresh the page, the image disappears. I am not able to store the image permanently for that user as with each refresh, the image goes away. Here is my code for store.js:

```
fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
if(user) {
    store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
    store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
}
})


export const store = new Vuex.Store({

state: {
    currentUser: null,
    userProfile: {},
    userProfilePic: null
},
actions: {
    clearData({commit}) {
        commit('setCurrentUser', null)
        commit('setUserProfile', {})
    },
    fetchUserProfile ({ commit, state }) {
        fb.usersCollection.doc(state.currentUser.uid).get().then(res 
=> {
            commit('setUserProfile', res.data())
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
},
mutations: {
    setCurrentUser(state, val) {
        state.currentUser = val
    },
    setUserProfile(state, val) {
        state.userProfile = val
    },
    setUserProfilePic(state, val) {``
        state.userProfilePic = val
    }
}

})
```

And here's the code that triggers on file change when the image is been uploaded:

```
<script>

const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            imageUrl: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onPickProfilePic () {
            this.$refs.fileInput.click();
        },
        filePicked (event) {
            var file = event.target.files[0]
            let filename = file.name
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser
            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(user.uid + 
'/profilePic/' + filename)
            var task = storageRef.put(file)
            var fileReader = new FileReader()
            fileReader.addEventListener('load', () => {
                this.userProfilePic = fileReader.result
            })
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file)
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState(['currentUser']),
        userProfilePic: {
            get () {
                return this.$store.state.userProfilePic
            },
            set (val) {
                this.$store.commit('setUserProfilePic', val)
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

I've gone through stackoverflow but no question seems to address my problem. If you need additional code, let me know. Many thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: Have you thought about saving in local storage or calling API in created lifecycle hook for per refresh ??

Comment: I've tried, but still nothing. Maybe there is something I'm doing wrong. I just can't seem to make it work.

Comment: The question is: does the currentUser disappears also?

Answer (score 0):

The thing with vue or vuex is that the with every reload all the data associated or stored in vue state or vuex state will be gone.

To get all those data with every reload, you have to call your respected API in the lifecycle hook.

For example, you want to get the user profile. On the pages `created` lifecycle hook call the API.

```
created () {
   this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile');
}
```

This will retrieve the data and will be stored in vuex. Thus you can use it anywhere in the application.